# In MIPS, what's the difference between signed addition, unsigned addition, signed subtraction and unsigned subtraction?

Tags: assembly, mips

```
add rd, rs, rt
addu rd, rs, rt
sub rd, rs, rt
subu rd, rs, rt
```

In MIPS, what's the difference between signed addition, unsigned addition, signed subtraction and unsigned subtraction? If their results are the same, what's the point to classified as using signed and unsigned methods?

Comment: IMO one of the worst names for an instruction addu since add and subtract cant be signed nor unsigned.  Only the flags and or detection mechanisms care (signed vs unsigned overflow, etc).  Mips doesnt use flags which makes this addu vs add even more confusing.

Answer (score 6):

The `u` simply means that they don't trap on overflow.

Quoting from "MIPS32 Architecture For Programmers Volume II":

> The term "unsigned" in the instruction name is a misnomer; this operation is 32-bit modulo arithmetic that does not trap on overflow. This instruction is appropriate for unsigned arithmetic, such as address arithmetic, or integer arithmetic environments that ignore overflow, such as C language arithmetic.